# Informix SQL: what does this syntax ||"-"|| means?

Tags: informix

I'm trying to understand what this sign means in Informix SQL >> `||"-"||`

An example of a query that has this is:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE field1||"-"||field2  
   IN (SELECT field1||"-"||field2 FROM table2)
```

Comment: `||` is the concatenation symbol

Comment: meaning field1.value-field2.value (as string) - in pseudo code ??

Comment: exactly that. field1 and field2 concatenated with a dash.

Answer (score 1):

Based on help provided on the comments, the answer is 
**CONCATENATION** ...

Comment: It is the standard SQL notation for string concatenation.  Note that if either operand of the `||` operator is NULL, the result is NULL, as required by the standard.

Answer (score 0):

That is interesting way of writing a SQL. Perhaps this is less confusing and more inline with standards.

```
DELETE FROM table1 
WHERE table1.field1 IN (SELECT table2.field1 
                        FROM table2 
                        WHERE table2.field2 = table1.field2)
```